# Getting parameters of a failed django-celery task

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

Is it possible to get the arguments used to call a particular failed celery task given the task's ID? I am using MongoDB as the broker and using the django-celery package.

I know that you can get the result pretty easily but wanted to know if you can do the same with the arguments used to call that task.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I managed to solve this problem by implementing a custom on_failure handler for my task as specified here:

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#handlers

I got the args info along with the error and saved it to a database.